# Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR Element not found in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

please i keep getting this error each time i refresh the page

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Element not found
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:10:36532)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.value (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:10:21771)
    at Proxy.renderChart (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??
```

the plugin works fine and it renders ,i've tried

```
npm i apexcharts
```

but the error is still there, please how to i go about this

Comment: Have you tried using the vue based library? https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/

Comment: Perhaps the DOM node (or CSS selector) you are providing to the chart library does not exist at that time yet ?